# How to deconstruct a variable in Typescript with a variable of the same name from an outer scope?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to use the variable name `username` and don't know how to do so in the following code:

```
  myFunction = async (email: string, password?: string): Promise<boolean> => {
    let username
    if (password) {
      { username } = await this.getUsernameAndDate(email, password)
    } else {
      username = await this.getUsernameByEmail({ email })
    }
    return this.sendUsername({ username })
  }
```

My linter complains that `{ username }` is unused:

> unused expression, expected an assignment or function call (no-unused-expression)tslint(1)

Iss there a propper way  to do this if I want to only use `username` everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the destructuring in parentheses:

```
({ username } = await this.getUsernameAndDate(email, password));
```

This is true for JS as well. If you were declaring (with `let`, `const`, etc) while destructuring, you wouldn't need the parentheses.

[More details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration)

Comment: Updated with link where you can understand why the parentheses are needed for `object destructuring`.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept this answer in a few minutes.